# Impossible Register Constraint in asm

Tags: c++, assembly

I am trying to use this code for multiplication in a C++ file.

```
LL mul(LL a, LL b, LL m)
{
   LL q;
   LL r;
   asm( "mulq %3;"
   "divq %4;"
   : "=a"(q), "=d"(r)
   : "a"(a), "rm"(b), "rm"(m));
   return r;
}
```

But this is showing impossible register constraint in asm error.

Comment: which compiler are you using and how are you instantiating this?

Comment: I am using gcc 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12

Comment: For the input operand, try using the same-place constraint, that is `"0"(a)`.

Comment: Tried, still same error

Comment: Just tested using gcc 4.6.4 on [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/), it seems to work fine either way. I doubt the minor number makes much of a difference. I assume `LL` is `long`. That said, I don't see much point in using asm for this.

Comment: I am just trying to learn asm. Not using it in a project as such. It is compiling fine on 4.6.4. Thanks for the help

Comment: Which processor is the assembly language for?  Processors can have different assembly languages.

Comment: It is on Intel i3-2100

Comment: I'm not getting "impossible constraint" either, although I can get "inconsistent operand constraints" if I compile the code for 32bit (I use `#define LL long long`).  Is there anything interesting in the calling code?